# /tmp full but... empty

Tags: fedora, tmpfs, core-dump, tmp

In a Python program, I use `np.memmaps`, which make use of the `/tmp` directory to handle massive arrays.
I make sure to clear `/tmp`regularly by running `rm -rf /tmp/*` every time I use this code. However recently, my code stopped working and threw me a "Bus error (core dumped)".

Now, even using auto-completion in the terminal results in: `bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device`.

typing `df -h` gives me, I think, the culprit:

```
tmpfs            32G   32G     0 100% /tmp
```

However, running `sudo rm -rf /tmp/*` only puts me back to

```
tmpfs            32G   30G  1,9G  94% /tmp
```

Any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: `rm -rf /tmp/*` won't delete hidden files/dirs. What's the output of `du -ah /tmp` and `lsof -a +L1 /tmp` (as `root`)?

Comment: sudo du -ah /tmp doesn't give anything interesting,

lsof -a +L1 /tmp returns a bunch of heavy files (which are indeed the memmaps I use in python), for example:

python3   14959 moissard   60u   REG   0,44 2871607712     0 377854 /tmp/tmpsb6pyut5/Bx.dat (deleted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command will let you learn the truth:

```
sudo lsof -n | grep /tmp |grep deleted
```

In Unix deleted files still exist in the filesystem and take space in it until the application using them closes the files or this application is terminated.

So, find the processes that have open deleted files and restart or terminate them.

It would be great to forcefully close the said file descriptors without terminating the apps using them but the Linux kernel doesn't support the `revoke()` system call: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14505

Comment: Ok yes, that helps. Now how do I remove deleted files that still hold space?

Comment: @ClémentMoissard see [Find and remove large files that are open but have been deleted](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68523)

Comment: Are they open? How?

Comment: I do not have any application open, typing "ps" returns:

``PID TTY          TIME CMD

 6592 pts/3    00:00:00 bash

 7218 pts/3    00:00:00 ps``

Comment: Oh right, your first command gives the answer:

``python3   14959 15526 moissard   60u      REG               0,44 2871607712     377854 /tmp/tmpsb6pyut5/Bx.dat (deleted)``

In this case, just typing `kill 14959` solved the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: The first column in your output is the PID. `kill -9 PID` will kill the process. But I guess it's something important, so you'd better figure out what is this process and why it's eating /tmp for breakfast ;-)

Comment: It is more efficient for `lsof` to process just the `/tmp` directory. To do that, use the comand `sudo lsof -n /tmp |grep deleted`